# Android Audio RTMP publish

Tags: android, ffmpeg, publish, rtmp, aac

Android client through the microphone to admit real-time voice, and the voice stream data sent to the server through RTMP, I want to achieve the client's transmission function, I am thinking is to convert AudioTrack ffmpeg ffmpeg (to AAC PCM), and then sent to the server, but the code is difficult to achieve.
Waiting for your answer，Thanks!

Comment: I have solved the problem，used rtmp + speex.I added a JNI Android interface, used to call the Recorder Audio interface, access PCM data, Speex as a dynamic library to JNI Android call, and then convert PCM into AAC data, and then sent to the server by RTMP.Thanks for jsdaya's answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use [voaacenc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencore-amr/files/vo-aacenc/) to encode pcm to aac, you can reference to AAC_E_SAMPLES.c in the project.
- Use librtmp rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/ to send aac packet, Reference this blog www.codeman.net/2014/01/439.html. (So sory I cannot post more than 2 links)

  - connect
  - send meta data
  - send aac spec data
  - send aac packets, the pts must increase
  - disconnect